# Logging in Unix Location

Tags: java, python, unix, logging

Is there a standard location as determined by the designers of the operating system where application logs should be kept within Unix systems? To expand, in cross-platform languages like python and java are there typically programmatic ways to access these locations to write your logs within them via libraries so the same code works on multiple systems?

Comment: You mean like `/var/log`?

Answer (score 0):

**As Klaus D. said,you should use /var/log to store your logs.**

/var is a short for “variable.” A place for files that may change often – especially in size, for example e-mail sent to users on the system, or process-ID lock files.

you can find very interesting information on the architecture of Unix files here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unix-file-system/